# How can I change the position and background of the Material Exposed dropdown menu icon?

Tags: android, android-layout

I am using Exposed dropdown menu as a spinner and would like to modify aspects of the icon. As it is a small spinner, the arrow icon is very centered and I would like to move it to the right. I would also like to change its background, currently it is like "selectableItemBackgroundBorderless" and I would like to set it to null.

[image]

This is my code:

```
            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                android:id="@+id/myTeamFormationSpinner"
                style="@style/CustomExposedDropMenu"
                android:layout_width="80sp"
                android:layout_height="30sp"
                android:layout_below="@id/myTeamTableData"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true">

                <AutoCompleteTextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:inputType="none" />
            </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

```
    <style name="CustomExposedDropMenu" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.FilledBox.ExposedDropdownMenu">
        <item name="boxBackgroundColor">@color/black</item>
        <item name="counterTextColor">@color/grayish_white</item>
        <item name="boxStrokeColor">@null</item>
        <item name="endIconTint">@color/grayish_white</item>
        <item name="boxCornerRadiusTopStart">7sp</item>
        <item name="boxCornerRadiusBottomStart">7sp</item>
        <item name="boxCornerRadiusTopEnd">7sp</item>
        <item name="boxCornerRadiusBottomEnd">7sp</item>
        <item name="boxStrokeWidth">0sp</item>
        <item name="boxStrokeWidthFocused">0sp</item>
    </style>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**POSITION**

You can't control the position of the original dropdown `icon`, the only way is to disable the default `icon` and add your own one into the dropdown.

First, disable the default dropdown icon by setting the `background` of the `Spinner` to `@null`:

```
<Spinner
     android:id="@+id/spinner_main"
     android:spinnerMode="dropdown"
     android:background="@null"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

Then create a layout resource `spinner_item_main.xml` with only one `TextView` which we can set a `drawable` on its right side (Download the arrow picture from [here](https://fonts.google.com/icons?selected=Material%20Icons:arrow_drop_down&icon.query=arrow_drop) or use your own one.):

```
<TextView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:gravity="left"
    android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
    android:drawableRight="@drawable/ic_arrow_drop_down_white_24dp"
    />
```

Finally set this `layout resource` when you initialize the `Spinner`, You can also provide a `resource` as the `dropdownView` (as what I have done):

```
ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Category>(this,R.layout.spinner_item_main,objects); // creates new ArrayAdapter with custom textviews for all elements including the first one (which is what we want)
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.spinner_dropdown_view_main); // Modifies all the elements when you click on the dropdown
    spinner.setAdapter(adapter); // sets the adapter to the spinner
```

With the attribute `padding` in the `TextView` can you adjust the space between arrow and text. Also with your `image resource` size itself.

**BACKGROUND COLOR**

Define in your `spinner_item_main.xml` the `background:color` of your `RelativeLayout` that includes the `Spinner` for example. So you can adjust everything as custom as possible.